# SVN Does not Store Password nor Username

Tags: macos, svn

I am using MacPorts SVN 1.8.9 on OSX Mavericks:

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
   compiled May 15 2014, 11:06:03 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
```

I have a rep with [svn2ftp](http://svn2ftp.com/) which I use to work with developers. It is a nice bridge between version control and the actual site. In  `~/.subversion/config` I have:

```
password-stores = keychain
store-auth-creds = yes
```

In `~/.subversion/servers` I have

```
username = myusername
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
```

But each time a do svn x I am asked for the password for the my OSX username instead of the username added and the password is also not stored in the KeyChain:

```
svn log
Authentication realm: <http://www.svn2ftp.com:80> repo
Password for 'osx-username':
```

The password is neither stored elsewhere as plain text.  Am I supped to make these changes elsewhere because this SVN is from MacPorts? I would not think so. What am I missing here? A config files rights issue? See here the permissions:

```
ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x    6 root    staff   204 Jan 23  2010 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 150 jasper  staff  5100 Jun 27 12:31 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff  4276 Jan 23  2010 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x    6 root    staff   204 Jan 23  2010 auth
-rw-r--r--    1 root     staff  6486 Jul  8 14:00 config
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff  7684 Jul  8 13:52 servers
```

under `/Users/jasper/.subversion`

Comment: based on thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661923/subversion-on-mac-refuses-to-get-password-from-keychain?rq=1 I did `sudo chown -R jasper:staff ~/.subversion/auth/` and ran `svn up` again, but I still had to add my details.

Comment: I so see username stored `jaspersmbp:svn.simple jasper$ cat a38ab297cc462606efaedummy0ee4331 
K 8
passtype
V 8
keychain
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 38
<http://www.svn2ftp.com:80> repo
K 8
username
V 20
jasper@domain.com
END` and it was just created so it is stored now.

Comment: On my mac, when the svn.simple file says 'keychain' the mac has stored the password outside of the file in the 'Keychain Access' app as a 'login' keychain for the specific subversion remote repository URL.  I open the app, choose the keychain 'login' and seach for the repository name, click on the recors, and a box pops up that can show the name if you choose it's 'Show Password' checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to make the owner of `~/.subversion/auth/` the user I was using. After that the username and password were stored in the auth folder under /Users/userinqu/.subversion/auth/svn.simple . And yes. It is all working now.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was that the keychain already had an entry stored for my credentials, but the access rights were not right.

Deleting the entry in the key chain app and then recreating it by using svn fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me as well! Actually, I double-clicked the entry with the credentials in the keychain manager and removed all `svn` entries from the authorization tab. (Cannot give you the exact English labels since my UI is in German.) Then, using `svn` finally asked for permissions again, which I could "grant forever".