# pycharm doesn't remember my SVN credential

Tags: svn, pycharm, credentials

I am on MacOS 1.9, using PyCharm 3.4.1 and having local SVN client 1.7 installed. My problem is that PyCharm keep on asking me for my credential each time the network was lost (so each time I open my computer, time for it to connect to the WiFi). Even if I click on "Save Credentials", it keeps on asking it to me. Whereas the SVN client (from classic terminal) is correctly caching my credentials. According to [JetBrain's page on the topic](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/authenticating-to-subversion.html) the credential are stored/read from the .subversion/auth which in my case seems correctly filled (and is used by my SVN client). So does anybody has a similar issue... and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a Mac thing more than a Pycharm thing as I'm also on OS X and had to follow answers for related questions, namely to:

1. [Edit `~/.subversion/config` to have `password-stores = keychain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661923/subversion-on-mac-refuses-to-get-password-from-keychain)
2. [Edit `~/.subversion/servers` to have `store-password = yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630418/svn-does-not-store-password-nor-username)
3. Then I had to use Terminal to go to my workspace and run `svn update` which then prompted me to allow access the Mac Keychain.  I said Always Allow.

It was only after that last step that PyCharm would then do SVN commands without asking for my password.  Per some documentation, on OS X one can only use `keystore` as a value for `password-stores`, but PyCharm doesn't try to use the Keychain directly, and doesn't forward on the permission request triggered by svn under the hood.  So, one has to use `svn` directly to see and accept the permission request.